# ブラウザ標準の404ページを表示させたい

Tags: php, apache, wordpress, http

■環境
wordpressにてサイト構築をしているのですが、会員制のサイトのため作成したURL以外は
ブラウザが標準で吐き出す404のページを表示させたいと考えています。

■試したこと
テンプレートで以下のように書くと

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: test
*/
header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
?>
```

ページが真っ白で表示されます。

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: test
*/
?>
```

こちらでも同様に真っ白で表示されます。

404.phpを削除してブラウザのキャッシュを削除して
表示してみたのですが404.phpのページが表示されてしまいます。
（ブラウザ側でキャッシュが残っているのか、wordpressコアで処理されているのか？
googleのキャッシュが表示されているのか？）

オリジナルの404ページを作る方法はたくさん公開されているのですが
ブラウザが標準で吐き出す404を意図的に表示する方法が見つけられませんでした。

※ブラウザが標準で吐き出す404というのは
IEとchromeでは存在しないURLにアクセスした際
404の表示が違いますがその生の404ページのことです。

こういったことを実現したい場合phpで可能なのでしょうか
それともapacheでの設定が必要になるのでしょうか。

Comment: response bodyを空にすれば良さそうです(すみません、PHPについて詳しくないので具体的な方法をお答えできません)が、そもそもそのような実装が妥当か、という問題もあるかと思います。手元のブラウザではFirefox(バージョン60)がそのようなレスポンスを受け取ると真っ白な表示となり、エンドユーザから見ると何が起こったのか分からない状態になってしまっています。

Comment: ↑について: [482874 - Provide a friendlier/more useful alternative when the user encounters a 404 error page.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=482874)

Comment: yukihaneさんコメントありがとうございます！
response bodyを空にですね。調査してみます。
実装の問題については今回会員のみの限定公開サイトを想定していて
ＰＣに少し詳しい方がサイトのコンテンツをコピー
するのを防ぐ目的で存在自体をなるべく知らせないように
すればいいのでは？ということで思いつきました。

検索エンジンにも公開しないサイトなんですが
問題が起こりそうでしたらぜひご教授願います。

Answer (score 1):

ブラウザの実装依存によりますが、少し調べてみました。

Internet Explorer ではレスポンスページのサイズが 512バイト以下であれば、[stackoverflow - カスタムエラーページが IE で表示されない](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022932/custom-http-error-page-is-not-displayed-in-internet-explorer) で書かれているようにブラウザ側の 404 ページが表示される動作になっています。(ただし、ユーザの設定でサーバ側のコンテンツを表示するように変更が可能です)

Google Chrome では [stackoverflow - Change Chrome 4xx Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841256/change-chrome-4xx-page#14848076) に書かれているように [chrome.webNavigation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onErrorOccurred) という API 経由で行うようですが、ハードルは高そうです。

Comment: Chromeの件について、それはChromeのExtensionがナビゲーションエラー時にハンドルするための話でありハードルというよりも質問の内容からは少し逸れそうです

Answer (score 0):

エラー時のサーバーレスポンスには

```
HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
```

の後ろに

```html
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>404 Not Found</TITLE>
```

…と続きがあります。

この内容は、apacheなどであれば
`/error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var`
に格納されたものです。

ブラウザによって独自に見えるのはStatus code 404を見て
付属のHTMLを無視しているケースです。

Comment: ZODIACさんご回答ありがとうございます！
apacheの設定になるのでしょうか。
参考にさせていただきあらためて調査してみます。